# GWT(CellTable):can i add 3 anchors in a cell

Tags: gwt

is it possible to add 3 anchors/ links   in one cell of GWT celltable

like this

```
                     add/delete/copy
```

these are 3 anchors in one cell with different click handlers for all three of them ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [CompositeCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html).

The idea will be for you to create 3 separate Column (or lightweight `HasCell` impementations using `ActionCell.Delegate` for example) objects for your actions and instead of adding them to the table one by one you would add them as part of the `CompositeCell`.

It may seem a little counterintuitive to add `HasCell` implementations into an actual cell, but here is an example, from another Stackoverflow question: [Does anyone have a working examples of ActionCells working within a CompositeCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524895/does-anyone-have-a-working-examples-of-actioncells-working-within-a-compositecel)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Anchor`s because you can't use any widgets.  However, you can render three different `<a>` elements and then override `onBrowserEvent` to catch clicks on them.

It may be simpler to use three separate columns and use a [`ClickableTextCell`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html) or something similar for each one.